# Keras LSTM crashes my computer?

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm trying to learn Keras, and made a really simple-looking model just to see what sort of errors I'd encounter.

```
input_layer = Input(shape=inp_size)

dens_layer = Dense(10000)(input_layer)
dens_layer_2 = Dense(10000)(dens_layer)
lstm_1 = LSTM(10000)(dens_layer_2)
lstm_2 = LSTM(10000)(lstm_1)
dense_layer = Dense(10000)(lstm_1)
dense_layer_2 = Dense(10000)(dense_layer)
output_layer = Dense(2)(dense_layer_2)
```

Dens_layer is constructed in 2 seconds, and dens_layer_2 is constructed in .07 seconds, but when I initialize the first LSTM layer it just continues doing... something... until my computer suddenly shuts off and restarts. It slows down my computer a bit, which another answer suggested was OS swapping, but I don't see why my computer would suddenly reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10000 units is really a lot, it probably needs a lot more resources than what you have. For comparison most Dense layers in ImageNet CNNs have 4096 units.